# How to check auth uid with the uid present in the collection data

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In firebase's firestore security rules:

I want to check the auth.uid with the uid data available in the document of the collection.

I tried using below code but it is not working....is there any way to get this done?

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /candidates/{candidate}/{document=**} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
  allow write: if true ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some improvement for your code. Check whether it would help to solve your problem.

Here in line 2 the syntax should be in the following format.

```
match /collection/document/collection
```

So because I think you referring to the documents in the candidate collection it should be as below if you don't want to the rule to be applied deep in the hierarchy.

```
match /candidates/{candidate}/ {
```

or as below if you need the deep hierarchy application of the rule.

```
match /candidates/{document==**}/ {
```

for the rule statements the first rule can be re-written as

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
```

since looking for the auth.uid in the request token will automatically block unauthenticated users since they won't have auth property on them.

For the second rule I guess you're using only for testing purposes. Since it is dangerous to allow anyone to edit documents without any permission. You can either same rule for the read operation or use a different rule to not allow unauthenticated write access.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but it is not working....it is still giving this error:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing how you are fetching those documents from the front end.

Comment: I am using this code to get the list of applications:: const getApplications = async () => {
    console.log("inside");
    const arr = [];
    const q = query(collection(db, "candidates"), where("company", "==", comp));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push(doc.data());
    });

    
    setApplications(arr);

    console.log("applications", arr);


   
  };